# Phalcon git installation bug?

Tags: php, phalcon

On my sever i successfully install phalcon version 0.6.0 through git.  These are the steps i used.

**git clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git**

**cd cphalcon/build**

**sudo ./install**

**restart the webserver**

I tried to update to version 0.7.0,  so i deleted the original folder and re-downloaded the git folder. I followed the same steps, after the install i check phpinfo. It installed correctly but, it installed a previous version(0.5.2).

I tried to install the extension multiple times but, it still gives me the old version.

is there something im doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the first 5 lines from `git log --oneline|head -5`?

I just cloned this git repo, and it looks like it's 0.7.0 to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find if you have any `phalcon.so` files laying around and they are used instead of the actual one. It could very well be that the 0.5.2 is somewhere in your system, referenced by your web server and the installation process cannot update it.

```
locate phalcon.so
```

Note: for my installation it was in `/usr/lib/php5/20100525/phalcon.so`

Check your `php.ini` or your `/etc/php/conf.d` folder for references to the extension. If there are some remove them.

Re-run the installation process again using the

```
cd build
sudo ./install
```

Note the script output, especially at the end. It will tell you where the extension was installed.

Note the folder and add the directive in the php.ini file and then restart your web server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: i followed this and removed all old php and extension files. i also rebuilt php and apache to have a fresh install. I installed all old extensions without a problem. When i tried to install this ext, it did not working. I looked at the outputted log and saw that it was installing the plugin in the wrong directory.
"Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/"

it should be installing it here "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525"

is there a way to change the directory where the plugin gets installed?
 Im using PHP Version 5.4.9

Comment: Or you can make sure that it loads the extension from the path you want: extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/phalcon.so

Comment: i tried to just move the extension to the new directory. I got a new error " PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: phalcon: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
" I think its compiling the module with the wrong php version

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have installed PHP 5.3 on CLI but PHP 5.4 on Apache/Nginx, make sure your 'phpize' command is pointing to the 5.4 one:

```
[#] whereis phpize
```

Once you know the correct path change the priority of the executable, delete the PHP 5.3 or add an alias in the bash console:

```
[#] alias phpize=/path/to/5.4/phpize
```

Then try to run ./install again